# How to do addon domain on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, dns

I have purchased domains and hosting from GoDaddy. In GoDaddy If I want to add multiple domains I use the option **addon domain**. So I can see all the domains listed in one directory like this:

```
public_html/ www.mysite1.com
public_html/ www.mysite2.com
public_html/ www.mysite3.com
```

On **AWS** I created an EC2 instance and then integrated one domain e.g `www.mysite1.com`. It is successfully integrated.

**Problem**

I want to know if, for example, I have 5 domains, then I have to create 5 instances and then integrate domains to them and then also access all of them individually from FTP? Is there a way like GoDaddy where all of the domains would be in one directory? Do I have to create multiple instances?

Comment: Hi @hellosheikh! Can you please provide more information? eg What are you doing on the servers? Are you running an Apache web server, or FTP servers? Are you saying that you'd like multiple domains to all point to the one server?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am using apache server and I can access files through FTP as well. and yes I would like multiple domains to point to one server

Comment: I imagine you should just create an Elastic IP Address, assign it to that server, then use DNS `A` records for each domain to point to that IP address.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts